# Persisting MemoryCache Content to File

Tags: c#, .net, caching

I'm intending to use the powerful caching libraries that are introduced in .Net 4.0 in a Windows Forms application. So far, `MemoryCache` does everything I need except for persisting its contents to a file. What I'm trying to do is persisting the cache to a file on application exit, and then when the application is opened again, I should be able to write from the file and put its contents in the `MemoryCache`. I know that I can simply serialize the instance into binary on disk, but then again, I wouldn't know how to convert it back to a `*MemoryCache*`.

Your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up implementing my own Cache project. Hopefully this will help someone somewhere:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Text;

namespace CachingDemo
{
    class CachedMemory
    {
        System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary cache = null;
        private String persistenceFilePath = null;
        private int cacheSizeLimit;
        public static readonly int CACHE_SIZE_NO_LIMIT = -1;

        public CachedMemory(int initialCapacity, int cacheSizeLimit, string persistenceFilePath)
        {

            this.cache = new System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary(initialCapacity);
            this.persistenceFilePath = persistenceFilePath;
            this.cacheSizeLimit = cacheSizeLimit;

        }

        public int getCacheSize()
        {
            return this.cache.Count;
        }

        public CachedMemory(int cacheSizeLimit, string cacheFilePath)
        {
            initializeCache(cacheFilePath, cacheSizeLimit);
        }

        private void initializeCache(string cacheFilePath, int cacheSizeLimit)
        {
            this.cacheSizeLimit = cacheSizeLimit;
            using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(cacheFilePath, FileMode.Open))
            {
                IFormatter bf = new System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter();
                this.cache = (System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary)bf.Deserialize(fileStream);
                fileStream.Close();
            }

            //In case the deserialized OrderedDictionary had more contents than the limit, we need to shrink it to make its size equal to the limit
            if (this.cacheSizeLimit != CACHE_SIZE_NO_LIMIT && this.cache.Keys.Count > this.cacheSizeLimit)
            {
                int difference = this.cache.Keys.Count - this.cacheSizeLimit;

                for (int i = 0; i < difference; i++)
                {
                    cache.RemoveAt(0);
                }
            }
        }

        public string get(string key)
        {
            return cache[key] as string;
        }

        public string get(int index)
        {
            return cache[index] as string;
        }


        public void add(string key, string value)
        {
            //An ordered dictionary would throw an exception if we try to insert the same key again, so we have to make sure that the newly
            //introduced key is not a duplicate.
            if (this.cache.Contains(key))
            {
                this.cache.Remove(key);

            }
            else
                if (this.cacheSizeLimit != CACHE_SIZE_NO_LIMIT && this.cache.Count == this.cacheSizeLimit)
                {
                    this.cache.RemoveAt(0);

                }

            this.cache.Add(key, value);
        }

        public void persist()
        {
            using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(persistenceFilePath, FileMode.Create))
            {
                IFormatter bf = new System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter();
                bf.Serialize(fileStream, this.cache);
                fileStream.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: so you just want cache strings? are you hiding a serialisation  mechanism somewhere?

Comment: The above example can work for objects instantiated using custom classes, given that they are defined as being serializable.